# Can I customize authentication in LDAP/radius/Tacas/Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, ldap, radius

Can I authorize a client using custom parameters in ldap/radius/active directory or tacas?
Like I want them to enter additional parameters along with their username/password when authenticating.

If so, how? Will I need to code it? Is this functionality build in?

Or is it not possible at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any LDAP server will only require a username and password to authenticate. You're free to collect whatever other information you need, but you will have to validate that other information yourself.